# Phonegap and Facebook - Idiots Guide

Tags: facebook, cordova

Right, I just feel the need to get this off my chest before I explode.

I have made an app using phonegap which actually works very smooth as it's using SVG and very simple but I feel this could be a very addictive little game. the only thing that is letting it down is that I want the user to be able to share their score on Facebook.

Facebook Connect plugin for Phonegap is the worst pile of crap I have ever come across. This is the millionth time I have come back to an Idea, thinking this plugin would have over time (I'm talking years) would have a simple step by step clear set of instructions on how to install but I have NEVER been able to get this working. Before anyone comments on "well why dont you post the errors" theres no point, every time it's a different problem, everyone on the internet cannot get this thing working it's pointless so please, I beg of you can you not post "there is a plugin which can do this easily", it CANT!!

Right, now my rant is over... I have come across this little plugin https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB which, on the face of things does what it says on the tin. My only problem is, (again no clear documentation anywhere on the web for setting up a Facebook app for someone who has never done it before) I dont know what platform to add and what settings to set.

Can anyone state, for a Phonegap application making HTTP requests to the Graph API, what the following should be:

1. Platform
2. App Domain
3. The Platform Basic Settings

If anyone can help it would be very much appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am using OpenFB successfully (almost..)
You don't need any special permissions for android application defined in facebook application. Just copy openfb.js library and look at [example code](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB/blob/master/index.html).

EDIT: actually I had small erorr in logic which caused me trouble, it wasn't openfb's error.